# Simple script in acrobat debugger SyntaxError: missing ; before statement

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm new to Acrobat javascript and am working out how to use the debugger. I entered the following in the console. It ran fine the first time.  However,  now I'm getting missing ; before statement error. This is what I'm trying to run and the message I'm getting:

```
let myNameArray = [('Chris','Jim','Marie','Stacy')];
let myNumArray = [10, 20, 25, 30];
myNameArray[2];
myNumArray[1];
        
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
1:Console:Exec
undefined
```

Am I missing something that has to do with the debugger?

I pared down the script to this:

```
let myNameArray = ['Chris', 'Jim', 'Marie', 'Stacy');
myNameArray = [0];
```

This script returned Chris.

I then added myNumArray code as above and it worked.  The only thing I did differently was to close all of my Acrobat windows and start from the beginning. It's confusing to me.

Comment: Why is there () is the array? why is there () around the code which is supposed to an an array? `myNumArray` is not an array, it is a number. `myNameArray` is an array that just contains `'Stacy'`. Your code basically looks like `let myNameArray = ['Stacy']; let myNumArray = 30;` because of the comma operator.

Comment: Removing the ( ) in myNameArray renders the same error.

Comment: Well you did not make myNumArray into an array

Comment: That was my mistake when I wrote the post.  I fixed it

Comment: And is `let myNameArray = [('Chris','Jim','Marie','Stacy')];` a mistake too? What is your actual code? Post the actual code that is causing the error....

Comment: I fixed the error I made with myNumArray.  If I remove the ( ) from myNameArray I get the same error. It doesn't matter if I include the ( ) in myNameArray or not. I get the same error either way.  This is the extent of the code snippet I'm trying to run.

Comment: Code above should have no errors unless your engine somehow hates the fact you are just referencing an array index without using it.

Answer (score 1):

The Acrobat JavaScript interpreter doesn't support "let".

Use...

```
var myNameArray = ['Chris', 'Jim', 'Marie', 'Stacy'];
var myNumArray = [10, 20, 25, 30];
```

Answer (score 0):

When your code runs you are basically getting the following

```
let myNameArray = ['Stacy'];
let myNumArray = 30;
```

The reason why is the comma operator. When you wrap the code in `()` you all of the sudden have a comma operator. The comma operator `,` evaluates each of its operands (from left to right) and returns the value of the last operand.

```js
const myNameArray = ['Chris', 'Jim', 'Marie', 'Stacy'];
const myNumArray = [10, 20, 25, 30];
console.log(myNameArray[2]);
console.log(myNumArray[1]);
```

Comment: What I am expecting if the code runs correctly is Maire and 20.  I've seen examples in other code snippets that declare text variables using [(xxxxxx, xxxxxx)] or [(xxxxxx)]

Comment: Using () really makes no sense inside of an array. I think you somehow are confusing () for [] for nested arrays. AKA `[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]`

Comment: I must be using an old reference.  What I read and the example that was posted used "let" to create and assign a variable, including an array.  The reference is on developer.mozilla.org website. Is this an example where Acrobat uses different rules for variable assignment?

Comment: let/const makes no difference here. You use let when you change the variable. AKA... `let foo = [1,2,3]; foo = [4,5,6];` When you use `const`, it will throw an error when you try to alter `foo`.